# R unexpected behaviour convert list to data.table when list is singular

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with a local repo, and stumbled on something that confuses my understanding of indexing a list.

```
as.data.table(
 available.packages(url, type="win.binary")[, c("Package","Version","Depends","Repository")]
)
```

If the repo at 'url' has several packages I get expected results:

```
     Package  Version       Depends                                     Repository
1: truncnorm   1.0-7  R (>= 2.15.0)        file:///D:/Repo/bin/windows/contrib/3.3
2:     yacca   1.1    R (>= 1.8.0), utils  file:///D:/Repo/bin/windows/contrib/3.3
```

But when the repo has 1 package only:

```
                                        V1
1:                               truncnorm
2:                                   1.0-7
3:                           R (>= 2.15.0)
4: file:///D:/Repo/bin/windows/contrib/3.3
```

It seems to have converted the list row to a column. Why does it treat a single list component as a vector (or is something else going on) ?

Comment: I suspect that this conversion is happening when you either call or subset `available.packages`. Rather than returning a character matrix, it returns a character vector. R does this simplification fairly regularly. If you don't want this behavior, `available.packages(url, type="win.binary")[, c("Package","Version","Depends","Repository"), drop=FALSE]` might work. See `help("[")` for more info on the drop argument

Comment: Thanks @lmo, that help page is exactly what I needed to be pointed to.

Comment: @ShayneH you can self-answer your question, or simply delete it

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @lmo

R will by default collapse a dimension if it is redundant.
To stop this behaviour use the option drop=FALSE

```
available.packages(url, type="win.binary")[, c("Package","Version","Depends","Repository"), drop=FALSE]
```